# Macro/VBA: Clear cells in a row based on values in a column, and loop through entire column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to write a macro in excel that will identify the first value in a row (A2) and then search the rest of the row to clear any cell with a greater value (C2:DGA2). I'd like to set this up such that the program loops through every row in the column (A2:A400), and clears the corresponding values.

I tried using the following code, which I modified from another post:

```
Sub clear_cell()
Dim v
v = Excel.ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TOP LINE").Range("B2").Value

Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Sheet1.Range("C2:DGJ2")

Dim r, c As Long
For r = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
    For c = 1 To UBound(Arr, 2)
        If Arr(r, c) > v Then
            Arr(r, c) = ""
        End If
    Next c
Next r

Sheet1.Range("C2:DGJ2") = Arr

End Sub
```

I modified it to fit my needs, but it only works for the first row. I need some help getting it to loop through every row in the first column.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: What are you working with two different sheets? are they not on the same sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm trying to write a macro in excel that will identify the first value in a row (A2) and then **search the rest of the row** to clear any cell with a greater value (C2:DGA2).

From the above statement, I am assuming that all ranges are in the same sheet. Your code works for me if I make a few changes. See this

```
Sub clear_cell()
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim Arr

    '~~> Set Range here
    Arr = Sheet1.Range("A2:DGJ400").Value

    For i = 1 To UBound(Arr, 1)
        For j = 2 To UBound(Arr, 2)
            If Arr(i, j) > Arr(i, 1) Then
                Arr(i, j) = ""
            End If
        Next j
    Next i

    '~~> Write back to the sheet
    Sheet1.Range("A2:DGJ400") = Arr
End Sub
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for the help. From what I can tell, I needed to fix my range?

Comment: Yes and other few things.. see the code that I posted above. Simply don't copy it.. try to understand it ;)

Answer (score 0):

give this a try:

```
Sub clear_cell()
    x = 2
    Do While x <= 400
    Y = Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(x, 2)).Value
    If Y < 100 Then Range(Cells(x, 2), Cells(x, 2)).FormulaR1C1 = ""
    x = x + 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

The 2 is the column range, in this case B.  Good Luck.

Comment: I just tried this and it deleted the entire column.

Comment: Adjust the Y < then range, its currently set for anything less then 100

Comment: Is there someway to make the Y< range set for value in the first column of each row?

Comment: If Y < range ("B1").value then